# TextView to display hint before text entered

Tags: android

How do I put text into empty TextView so it goes away when user starts typing? Just like here in StackOverflow under "Tags" field.

Same approach used in GMail client. That will save me some space - no need to create labels..

Comment: Probably you need something like  this -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747809/android-edittext-gmail-like-to-field

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Throw an `android:hint="hint text"` into your `EditText` xml tag.

Comment: The OP is asking about the `TextView`, not the `EditText`. Maybe you need to edit your answer to reflect this.

Comment: There is no hint for TextView. The text set will always show. Hint is required only for EditText

Answer (score 6):

As haphazard said or programatically you can use...

`setHint(CharSequence hint)` or `setHint(int resId)`.

The equivalent to the resource id in xml would be `android:hint="@string/hint_text"` (for example).