# Android EditText Gmail like to field

Tags: android, gmail, android-edittext

I'm working at an app, and I'm trying to make a gmail like "To" field, which has blocks inside which cannot be edited once added, but just removed entirely (like in the attached image). If it can have an image too, that would be perfect.
[image: gmail "To" field]

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318551/creating-a-custom-edittext-with-tag-like-feature

Comment: HI Did u achieved this Please let me know. i am also trying to implement like this, but getting somany problems @Ciprian

Comment: In the end it worked, but it gave me a lot of headaches at the time :)

Comment: @Ciprian Hey Please Post sample code if u have .. other wise please answer this qn. if u know..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780756/android-issue-with-image-span-replacement-in-different-android-versions-for-the

Comment: Just follow the instructions of CommonsWare, that pointed me to finding the solution

Comment: I have some issue. Please hv a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676347/setting-multiple-custom-elements-to-multiautocompletetextview-android

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This technique -- referred to as "chips" -- is discussed by Roman Nurik in [a Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092/posts/WUd7GrfZfiZ). He, in turn, points to [Macarse's answer here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090711/android-labels-or-bubbles-in-edittext/8128848#8128848). They, in turn, point to [the implementation of this UI](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/) that you see in the stock messaging client.

Comment: @Gopinath: AFAIK, yes. If you are having problems with getting it to work, open up a new StackOverflow question and supply the details.

Comment: @CommonsWare , I tried to make use of the chips UI following the Google+ post. It has lot of referrences to the Android4.0 framework classes and I gave it up.

Since then, there seems to have been better samples provided in the community. One of my preferred answers is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812316/contact-bubble-edittext/10864568#10864568

Comment: @CommonsWare you are right but it is very hard to understand and implement the code in stock mms application. I could not do it. I wish it can be reused easy

Comment: @CommonsWare I know but customizing it and using an populating it with an online data seems hard to me.

Comment: @CommonsWare i can not import
https://github.com/Derelicte/android_frameworks/tree/master/ex/chips . i think those are developed in ndk environment. i am unable to test or  use that code. Any Straight or good tutorial for chips implementation in multi autocomplete textview

Comment: @CommonsWare please check the link for my SO Question . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561858/how-add-and-delete-the-contact-bubbles-properly-in-multiautocompletetextview-wit

Answer (score 11):

I open-sourced our solution [TokenAutoComplete on github](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete). Mine has been tested back to 2.2. I designed my code to allow pretty simple implementations and customizations.

Here's an example implementation using my library:

Subclass TokenCompleteTextView

```
public class ContactsCompletionView extends TokenCompleteTextView {
    public ContactsCompletionView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected View getViewForObject(Object object) {
        Person p = (Person)object;

        LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)l.inflate(R.layout.contact_token, (ViewGroup)ContactsCompletionView.this.getParent(), false);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(p.getEmail());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object defaultObject(String completionText) {
        //Stupid simple example of guessing if we have an email or not
        int index = completionText.indexOf('@');
        if (index == -1) {
            return new Person(completionText, completionText.replace(" ", "") + "@example.com");
        } else {
            return new Person(completionText.substring(0, index), completionText);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout code for contact_token (you can use any kind of layout here or could throw an ImageView in if you want images in the token)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/token_background"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Token backgound drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#ffafafaf" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Person object code

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public Person(String n, String e) { name = n; email = e; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getEmail() { return email; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return name; }
}
```

Sample activity

```
public class TokenActivity extends Activity {
    ContactsCompletionView completionView;
    Person[] people;
    ArrayAdapter<Person> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        people = new Person[]{
                new Person("Marshall Weir", "marshall@example.com"),
                new Person("Margaret Smith", "margaret@example.com"),
                new Person("Max Jordan", "max@example.com"),
                new Person("Meg Peterson", "meg@example.com"),
                new Person("Amanda Johnson", "amanda@example.com"),
                new Person("Terry Anderson", "terry@example.com")
        };

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Person>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, people);

        completionView = (ContactsCompletionView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        completionView.setAdapter(adapter);
        completionView.setPrefix("To: ");
    }
}
```

Layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.tokenautocomplete.ContactsCompletionView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have some issue. Please hv a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676347/setting-multiple-custom-elements-to-multiautocompletetextview-android

Comment: How do you add an image using this library to the chip?