# How does Gmail manage to put a ViewGroup inside the EditText portion of a MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-layout, gmail, autocompletetextview

This is easy to verify

- Open the Gmail app on android
- Click on Compose
- Add 2 or more contacts in the `To` field

Notice how the contacts inside the EditText are formatted. They are not mere strings of emails, each looks like a `TextView` with a `compoundDrawable`. But then, even more than a TextView, you can click on each one of them. And when you do click, an `X` button shows up so that you can delete the one you clicked. It’s pretty awesome.

The problem is I can’t find any documentation online on how Google’s Gmail team is doing it. Does anyone know how and don’t mind showing an example code with xml and java portions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Add and delete the Contact Bubbles properly in multiautocompletetextview with space tokenizer like gmail to field in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561858/how-add-and-delete-the-contact-bubbles-properly-in-multiautocompletetextview-wit)

Answer (score 0):

You should Take Look at this.

[How Add and delete the Contact Bubbles properly in multiautocompletetextview with space tokenizer like gmail to field in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561858/how-add-and-delete-the-contact-bubbles-properly-in-multiautocompletetextview-wit)

I request you to use Search before posting questions. Its most likely that a feature or technique could be implemented already by someone.