# Android- Issue with Image Span Replacement in different android versions for the MultiAutoCompleteTextview Text

Tags: html, android, autocompletetextview

> I Am adding the customized Clickable spans to my
>   MultiAutoCompleteTextview. After adding 2 or more Contacts in That
>   Edit Text. i am replacing the extra Spans to Image Span with Text
>   Contains Count . My problem is that count is displaying different in
>   lower end devices(i.e., 2.2) and higher end devices(i.e., 4.0). Please
>   have a look into the below Pictures.
>
> Higher End Devices.
>   [image: Higher End Devices it is looking like this]
>
> LOwer End Devices
>   [image]

So problem with Higher end devices. each extra chip is replacing the count 2 times. 
Here is the code for replacing the extra chip PLease find it.

```
void createMoreChipPlainText() {

    Editable text = getText();
    int start = 0;
    int end = start;
    for (int i = 0; i < CHIP_LIMIT; i++) {
        end = movePastTerminators(mTokenizer.findTokenEnd(text, start));
        start = end; // move to the next token and get its end.
    }
    // Now, count total addresses.
    start = 0;
    int tokenCount = countTokens(text);
    MoreImageSpan moreSpan = createMoreSpan(tokenCount - CHIP_LIMIT);
    SpannableString chipText = new SpannableString(text.subSequence(end,
            text.length()));
    chipText.setSpan(moreSpan, 0, chipText.length(),
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    text.replace(end, text.length(), chipText);

    mMoreChip = moreSpan;
}
```

Is there any issue with replace method for editable class in android. Any one have any idea about this issue. please post your suggestions here

Comment: Android Tokenized Auto-Complete, a New Splitwise Open-Source Project [please refer this link](http://blog.splitwise.com/2013/09/24/android-tokenized-auto-complete-a-new-splitwise-open-source-project/)