# why doesnt android:inputType="textMultiLine|textEmailAddress" allow multiple lines

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText input field that needs to accept multiple email addresses.
e.g. on multiple lines.
however by setting `android:inputType="textMultiLine|textEmailAddress"`
the `textEmailAddress` options stops multiple lines being entered.
I've searched google and SO and all the "solutions" do not fix this.
Whats a working solution?

Comment: The answer is why it should ???

Comment: the question is.. why it doesnt????

Comment: yes the answer is why it should because its email and do you expect it to be multiline so there is no two line email so it doesn't do with emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however by setting android:inputType="textMultiLine|textEmailAddress"
>   the textEmailAddress options stops multiple lines being entered.

`textEmailAddress` and `textMultiline` are hints to the IME (input method editor). There are *many* input method editors available on Android devices, and not all will necessarily honor things the way that you want. I am not terribly surprised that `textEmailAddress` and `textMultiline` will not work together on some IMEs.

Here are some options:

1. Just use `textMultiline` and hope the user does not attack you with pitchforks for the hassle of getting to the <kbd>@</kbd> key.
2. Use more than one `EditText` widget. For example, you might have one (or a couple) of `textEmailAddress` `EditText` widgets, plus a `+` `ImageButton` to add more, collecting one address per `EditText`.

Comment: its not just the "hassle" of entering "@" textEmailAddress also gives the .com key, i am also looking at adding in keys for .gmail etc. I am trying to create a NOTEPAD application that allows the user to enter Multiples of many types of text input, this means i will only present a single input field

Comment: @user423199: "its not just the "hassle" of entering "@" textEmailAddress also gives the .com key" -- both `@` and `.com` will vary by IME and will not always be present, even if you have `textEmailAddress`. "i am also looking at adding in keys for .gmail etc." -- you will have to write your own IME for that and ask users to use it. "I am trying to create a NOTEPAD application" -- a notepad should not use `textEmailAddress`, IMHO, since notes are not always email addresses.

Comment: commonsware, thanks for taking the time to look at this, ... maybe referring to my app as a "NOTEPAD" was too vague. i realise i will have to write my own IME to deploy with my "NOTEPAD", i may look at creating a custom EditText field to "work round" this feature to allow multiple email addresses

Comment: @user423199: since the behavior of the IME is up to the implementer of the IME, if you are creating your own, you can address the `textMultiline|textEmailAddress` there. However, bear in mind that expecting users to switch to your IME to use your app may not prove to be popular.

Comment: i realise the IME options is a "Stretch"

Answer (score 1):

Try this....It's working for me

1. android:singleLine="false"
2. android:lines="10" //max lines
3. android:minLines = "3" // This will be the height

have a look at this EditText

```
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/addr_edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textMultiLine"
    android:lines="20"
    android:minLines="5"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

Comment: i cut and pasted this into my layout, and it will not allow multiple lines

Comment: it's working for me..i have tested it on my device running 4.0 ICS

Comment: which API Level you are targeting??

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18"

Comment: Try giving your EditText a Specific Height like 200dp or 150dp. You can take width according to your needs....Try modified code..

Comment: both the solutions are working for me....i think you are doing something wrong...can you post your xml code in your question..

Comment: i copied and pasted your xml into my app. that doesnt work for me, what else can i try?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `MaxLine attribute` for EditText

Try this code:

```
  <EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" <!-- Multiline input -->
    android:lines="8" <!-- Total Lines prior display -->
    android:minLines="6" <!-- Minimum lines -->
    android:gravity="top|left" <!-- Cursor Position -->
    android:maxLines="10" <!-- Maximum Lines -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- Height determined by content -->
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" <!-- Fill entire width -->
    android:scrollbars="vertical" <!-- Vertical Scroll Bar -->
    android:singleLine="false" <!--Enables insertion of new line with "enter" -->
  />
```

Comment: yes this works fine... however i also need to set textEmailAddress, which "breaks" the multi line

Comment: sorry i didn't get you. Can you elaborate a little.

Comment: @user423199 the email address is an atomic thing it doesn't break in multiline

Comment: i dont want to break an email address... i need to enter more than one email address in a single edittext field

Comment: this code doesn't fulfil my needs as it doesn't allow multiple email addresses, as the "New Line" key is visible, however you cannot insert a new line inside an edittext input field that has an input type of textEmailAddress

Answer (score 0):

**If you are looking to add multiple recipient like gmail or any email...**

Please go though the similar post

**[Android EditText Gmail like to field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747809/android-edittext-gmail-like-to-field)**

Or You can make Multiple E-mail Autocomplete TextView.

```
public class ContactsAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public ContactsAutoComplete(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setThreshold(0);
        this.setUpContacts();
    }

    public ContactsAutoComplete(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setThreshold(0);
        this.setUpContacts();
    }

    public ContactsAutoComplete(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setThreshold(0);
        this.setUpContacts();
    }

    // --- comma separating stuff

    private String previous = ""; //$NON-NLS-1$
    private String seperator = ", "; //$NON-NLS-1$

    /**
     * This method filters out the existing text till the separator and launched
     * the filtering process again
     */
    @Override
    protected void performFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode) {
        String filterText = text.toString().trim();
        previous = filterText.substring(0,
                filterText.lastIndexOf(getSeperator()) + 1);
        filterText = filterText.substring(filterText.lastIndexOf(getSeperator()) + 1);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(filterText)) {
            super.performFiltering(filterText, keyCode);
        }
    }

    /**
     * After a selection, capture the new value and append to the existing text
     */
    @Override
    protected void replaceText(final CharSequence text) {
        super.replaceText(previous + text + getSeperator());
    }

    public String getSeperator() {
        return seperator;
    }

    public void setSeperator(final String seperator) {
        this.seperator = seperator;
    }

    // --- contacts stuff

    private void setUpContacts() {
        ContactListAdapter adapter = new ContactListAdapter(getContext(), null);
        setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("nls")
    public static class ContactListAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable {
        public ContactListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, c);
            mContent = context.getContentResolver();
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final TextView view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);
            view.setText(convertToString(getCursor()));
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            ((TextView) view).setText(convertToString(cursor));
        }

        @Override
        public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
            return cursor.getString(1) + " <" + cursor.getString(2) +">";
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) {
                return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
            }

            StringBuilder buffer = null;
            String[] args = null;
            if (constraint != null) {
                constraint = constraint.toString().trim();
                buffer = new StringBuilder();
                buffer.append("UPPER(").append(People.NAME).append(") GLOB ?");
                buffer.append(" OR ");
                buffer.append("UPPER(").append(ContactMethods.DATA).append(") GLOB ?");
                args = new String[] { constraint.toString().toUpperCase() + "*",
                        constraint.toString().toUpperCase() + "*" };
            }

            return mContent.query(Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_EMAIL_URI,
                    PEOPLE_PROJECTION, buffer == null ? null : buffer.toString(), args,
                    Contacts.People.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
        }

        private final ContentResolver mContent;
    }

    private static final String[] PEOPLE_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        People._ID,
        People.NAME,
        ContactMethods.DATA
    };
}
```

**Use This Custom AutoCompleteTextView like below**

```
<YOUR_PACKAGE.ContactsAutoComplete
        android:id="@+id/emails"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Send To"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

**Add this permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Please refer below blog.

http://www.betaful.com/2011/02/multiple-e-mail-autocomplete-in-android/

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textEmailAddress"
```

make single line  as false.this will allow multiple lines in your edit text.

Comment: this doesnt fix the problem for me